# Which is the Best Cipher Mode and Padding Mode for AES Encryption?

Tags: encryption, pci-dss, aes, cipher-selection, nist

> **As per PCI-DSS 3.4 requirement:**

For storing Credit Card Data **Strong Cryptography** should be used.

I decided to use AES Encryption which is a strong and mostly recommended crypto for encrypting Credit Card Details.

I saw that AES has Cipher Mode and Padding Mode in it.

When I searched i found that according to [NIST Special Publication 800-38A](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38a/sp800-38a.pdf), it specifies five confidentiality modes of operation for symmetric key cipher algorithm.

So I'm totally confused whether can I use anyone of the five cipher modes or is there best one among the five as listed below:

> Cipher Modes:

1. ECB
2. CBC
3. OFB
4. CFB
5. CTR

**Which is the best Cipher mode among the five?**

**Also which is the best Padding Mode for AES Ecryption?**

Answer (score 71, accepted):

## **THIS ANSWER IS FROM 2014.**

Practices in cryptography have moved on a lot since I originally wrote this. I have added an update for 2021 further down.

Original answer for reference:

---

"Best" is rather subjective - it depends on your requirements. That said, I'll give you a general overview of each mode.

**ECB** - Electronic Code Book. This mode is the simplest, and transforms each block separately. It just needs a key and some data, with no added extras. Unfortunately it sucks - for a start, identical plaintext blocks get encrypted into identical ciphertext blocks when encrypted with the same key. Wikipedia's [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_block_chaining#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29) has a great graphic representation of this failure.

Good points: Very simple, encryption and decryption can be run in parallel.

Bad points: Horribly insecure.

**CBC** - Cipher Block Chianing. This mode is very common, and is considered to be reasonably secure. Each block of plaintext is xor'ed with the previous block of ciphertext before being transformed, ensuring that identical plaintext blocks don't result in identical ciphertext blocks when in sequence. For the first block of plaintext (which doesn't have a preceding block) we use an *initialisation vector* instead. This value should be unique per message per key, to ensure that identical messages don't result in identical ciphertexts. CBC is used in many of the SSL/TLS cipher suites.

Unfortunately, there are attacks against CBC when it is not implemented alongside a set of strong integrity and authenticity checks. One property it has is block-level malleability, which means that an attacker can alter the plaintext of the message in a meaningful way *without knowing the key*, if he can mess with the ciphertext. As such, implementations usually include a HMAC-based authenticity record. This is a tricky subject though, because even the order in which you perform the HMAC and encryption can lead to problems - look up "MAC then encrypt" for gory details on the subject.

Good points: Secure when used properly, parallel decryption.

Bad points: No parallel encryption, susceptible to malleability attacks when authenticity checks are bad / missing. But when done right, it's very good.

**OFB** - Output Feedback. In this mode you essentially create a stream cipher. The IV (a unique, random value) is encrypted to form the first block of keystream, then that output is xor'ed with the plaintext to form the ciphertext. To get the next block of keystream the previous block of keystream is encrypted again, with the same key. This is repeated until enough keystream is generated for the entire length of the message. This is fine in theory, but in practice there are questions about its safety. Block transforms are designed to be secure when performed once, but there is no guarantee that *E(E(m,k),k)* is secure for every independently secure block cipher - there may be strange interactions between internal primitives that haven't been studied properly. If implemented in a way that provides partial block feedback (i.e. only part of the previous block is bought forward, with some static or weakly random value for the other half) then other problems emerge, such as a short key stream cycle. In general you should avoid OFB.

Good points: Keystream can be computed in advance, fast hardware implementations available

Bad points: Security model is questionable, some configurations lead to short keystream cycles

**CFB** - Cipher Feedback. Another stream cipher mode, quite similar to CBC performed backwards. Its major advantage is that you only need the encryption transform, *not* the decryption transform, which saves space when writing code for small devices. It's a bit of an oddball and I don't see it mentioned frequently.

Good points: Small footprint, parallel decryption.

Bad points: Not commonly implemented or used.

**CTR** - Counter Mode. This essentially involves encrypting a sequence of incrementing numbers prefixed with a nonce (*number used once*) to produce a keystream, and again is a stream cipher mode. This mode does away with the problems of repeatedly running transforms over each other, like we saw in OFB mode. It's generally considered a good mode.

Good points: Secure when done right, parallel encryption and decryption.

Bad points: Not many. Some question the security of the "related plaintext" model but it's generally considered to be safe. (**Update, 2021:** I'm not sure why I didn't mention this back in 2014, but stream ciphers are inherently malleable, meaning that an attacker can flip arbitrary bits in your plaintext if you fail to verify the integrity and authenticity of the ciphertext properly)

---

Padding modes can be tricky, but in general I would always suggest PKCS#7 padding, which involves adding bytes that each represent the length of the padding, e.g. `04 04 04 04` for four padding bytes, or `03 03 03` for three. The benefit over some other padding mechanisms is that it's easy to tell if the padding is corrupted - the longer the padding, the higher the chance of random data corruption, but it also increases the number of copies of the padding length you have. It's also trivial to validate and remove, with no real chance of broken padding somehow validating as correct.

---

In general, stick with CBC or CTR, with PKCS#7 where necessary (you don't need padding on stream cipher modes) and use an authenticity check (HMAC-SHA256 for example) on the ciphertext. Both CBC and CTR come recommended by Niels Ferguson and Bruce Schneier, both of whom are respected cryptographers.

That being said, there are *new* modes! [EAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode) and [GCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) have recently been given a lot of attention. GCM was put into the TLS 1.2 suite and fixes a lot of problems that existed in CBC and stream ciphers. The primary benefit is that both are *authenticated modes*, in that they build the authenticity checks into the cipher mode itself, rather than having to apply one separately. This fixes some problems with padding oracle attacks and various other trickery. These modes aren't quite as simple to explain (let alone implement) but they are considered to be very strong.

---

### Update for 2021

As of November 2021, CBC is generally no longer recommended for use in new systems. You should use an [AEAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption#Authenticated_encryption_with_associated_data_(AEAD)) such as ChaCha20-Poly1305 or AES-GCM.

CBC is highly fraught in practice because you must be very careful about the padding scheme you choose and the integrity and authenticity checks you apply. If the authenticity record is applied to the plaintext instead of the ciphertext (i.e. MAC-then-encrypt) then an attacker may be able to utilise a [padding oracle side-channel attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle_attack) to decrypt data by repeatedly sending modified packets to a receiver that attempts to decrypt them. If an attacker can modify the IV in transit, because it wasn't protected by an authenticity record, they can modify the first decrypted block of plaintext by manipulating the IV. The padding scheme itself must also be chosen to be resistant to ambiguous decoding, e.g. an all-zero padding scheme would result in any trailing zeroes in the actual message to be stripped.

CTR is less fraught. There's no padding, since CTR ciphertexts are the same length as their plaintexts. An attacker who modifies the IV can only garble the whole message - modifying the IV doesn't allow them to make meaningful modifications. However, stream ciphers still have *bit-level* malleability, meaning that a ciphertext that is not authenticated (e.g. with a MAC) can be manipulated to flip arbitrary bits in the plaintext, at any position. Whereas in CBC the use of MAC-then-encrypt is liable to completely break the system, in CTR mode (and in other stream ciphers) it not guaranteed to be as catastrophic.

AES-CBC is still widely used in TLS 1.2, but it has taken many years of careful engineering to make that implementation safe enough for general use. Implementing CBC mode in your own system is ill-advised. All CBC mode cipher suites have been removed from TLS 1.3. You should consider it to be deprecated, and use it only where you must interoperate with a system that cannot be upgraded to use a more modern scheme.

AES-CTR is also still around, but again is generally not recommended for new designs. It's *maybe* less problematic than CBC, but if we're talking about picking a cipher suite for TLS then there's barely any difference.

AEADs are now preferred. AEAD stands for Authenticated Encryption with Associated Data. What this means, in practice, is that you can encrypt some message (thereby providing confidentiality), authenticate it (thereby providing integrity and authenticity), and *also* authenticate some associated data that does not require confidentiality, all within the cipher mode itself. This removes the burden of implementing authenticity validation separately. The associated data is often used to attach an IV or other protocol-specific data to the encrypted message in a way that prevents tampering, which again alleviates the need to implement this separately.

AES-GCM is an AEAD based on AES-CTR and Galois Message Authentication Code (GMAC) for message authentication. It is supported in TLS 1.2 and 1.3 and offers a meaningful security upgrade from CBC and CTR modes. Modern x86 processors, and higher-power ARM processors, include specialised instructions that accelerate both AES encryption/decryption operations and Galois field calculations, making AES-GCM very fast on these platforms. A downside to GCM is that it is tricky to implement safely, and it is very unforgiving if it fails. Neither of these things are a concern if you're just consuming AES-GCM in a protocol like TLS, but [they are issues that matter to cryptographers](https://soatok.blog/2020/05/13/why-aes-gcm-sucks/).

[CCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode) is another AEAD, this time based on a combination of CBC and [CBC-MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC). While CBC itself is considered weak, for the reasons I described above, the construction of CCM does not fall foul of those specific problems. The CBC-MAC part provides authenticity, and is itself constructed from CBC operations. CCM is viewed somewhat less favourably than other AEADs in terms of the cryptography, but it saves you implementing Galois field operations on platforms that don't have acceleration instructions for it. AES-CCM is available in both TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3. There is also a variant with a truncated authentication tag, referred to as `CCM_8`, which uses an 8-byte (64-bit) authentication tag rather than the usual 16-byte (128-bit) authentication tag - you can read about this [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/63796/why-does-tls-1-3-support-two-ccm-variants).

I mentioned EAX mode previously. This hasn't really caught on. It's far slower than GCM. There's also a variant called "EAX(prime)", which is completely broken.

Another lesser-used AEAD is [Offset Codebook Mode (OCB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCB_mode). This was, in theory, a good AEAD cipher mode. It uses Galois fields, but it's easier to implement than GCM. There are three variants. OCB1 is not an AEAD. OCB2 adds AEAD functionality. OCB3 is a newer version. OCB2 is broken - there's a full plaintext recovery attack on it. OCB3 is still considered secure. None of this really matters in practice, however, because author patented it and applied a restrictive exemption clause that allowed free implementation only in GPL licensed code. This was later relaxed to any open source license approved by the OSI, but this remained a significant practical encumbrance. The patents were abandoned by February 2021, but by this point everybody had standardised on other modes. OCB is largely irrelevant now, despite potentially being better than GCM.

ChaCha20-Poly1305 is currently (as of November 2021) regarded as one of the better AEADs. It isn't strictly a "cipher mode", because it's a specific combination of a cipher and a MAC - it is constructed from the [ChaCha20 stream cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20#ChaCha_variant) (a variant of Salsa20) and the [Poly1305 message authentication code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly1305). It is generally faster and more power-efficient than AES-GCM and AES-CCM when specialised hardware acceleration is not available. It has strong security properties and attractive practical properties for implementers. It is available in TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3, and is currently the default cipher used in libsodium's secret box API. You should prefer it in new systems.

In summary:

- ECB - Don't use it. There are a very small number of situations where ECB is the correct choice, but unless you're a cryptographer you'll almost never run into them.
- CBC - Theoretically secure, but difficult to get right in practice. Has been the cause of many vulnerabilities in TLS over the years, due to the use of MAC-then-CBC. Consider this to be deprecated. Acceptable in legacy systems that have careful implementations, but should not be used in new designs.
- OFB - Don't use it. It's an unusual mode that lacks desirable properties and has issues with cycle length.
- CFB - Don't use it. Again, it's an unusual mode.
- CTR - Theoretically secure, and fewer footguns than CBC. Still needs careful implementation to provide strong authenticity. Consider this to be deprecated. Acceptable in legacy systems that have careful implementations, but should not be used in new designs.
- GCM - A strong, widely supported AEAD. Tricky to implement safely if timing and power analysis side-channel attacks are a concern, but if you're using it in a standard protocol implementation (e.g. openssl) it's fine. Appropriate for new designs.
- CCM - Another strong, widely-supported AEAD. Can be a little slow, but easier to implement than AES-GCM and supports truncated tags. Appropriate for new designs, but generally not the first choice.
- EAX - No reason to use this mode. It's no more secure than GCM, which is faster.
- OCB - Theoretically a good AEAD, but patent encumbrance prevented it from catching on. Maybe it'll take off in future? For now you can ignore it.
- ChaCha20-Poly1305 - A specific cipher and MAC pair rather than a mode, but it's one of the best options available as of November 2021 if you're trying to pick a cipher suite. Widely supported. I'd recommend making it your preferred option.

Comment: Almost three years later, has the situation changed? Have EAX and GCM (or yet other methods) moved up in the list of recommendations? (Also, are there references for the quality claims you make? Not that I don't want to believe you, but citeable evidence would easy my conscience.)

Comment: GCM has definitely gained popularity, particularly in TLS.

Comment: I've added a major update for November 2021, to reflect 7 years of changes in the field of cryptography, alongside 7 years of additional experience on my part.

Comment: "As of November 2021, CBC is generally no longer recommended for use in new systems." - @Polynomial are you quoting some some official recommendation here? If so it would be great if you could link it. Thanks. Helpful review.

Comment: @PrancingCrabulon Not quoting from anything in particular, but for example take a look at the cipher suites in TLS 1.3, or the ciphers used in the underlying implementation of libsodium. They're all AEAD block modes like GCM, or authenticated stream ciphers like ChaCha20-Poly1305. By comparison CBC is problematic because it's too easy to get wrong, due to padding oracles, malleability, fault injection, etc.